# Please help: How can I scrape this web page?

Tags: post, coldfusion, scrape, cfhttp

There's a site that offers a search service. You enter a number, search, and it returns results. What I want to do is run that search programmatically through coldfusion instead of having to go to the site and search manually.

This is what the form in the web page I'd like to read/scrape looks like (as seen when viewing the page source):

```
<form id="frmNumID" name="frmNum" action="" method="post">

    <TABLE border=0 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0>
     <TR>
      <TD align="center">
         <label class="NumLabel" for="Num" ACCESSKEY="1">ENTER NUM:</label>
        <input class="NumInput" id="Num" name="inputNum"  onfocusin="select()"  title="Num Input" tabindex="1" type="text" value=""  size ="29" maxlength="17" >&nbsp;&nbsp;

      </TD>

      <TD align="center">
         <input class="NumInput" title="Submit Num" tabindex="2" type="image" src="/include/pics/SubmitBtn.jpg" value="submit" ACCESSKEY="2">
      </TD>
     </TR>
     </TABLE>

     <TABLE border=0 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0>
     <TR>    
      <TD colspan="2" align="center">

        <input type="radio" name="displayType" value="NONE"   Checked  />No Pictures&nbsp;&nbsp;                          
        <input type="radio" name="displayType" value="STUFF"    /> Other Stuff&nbsp;&nbsp;                
        <input type="radio" name="displayType" value="MORESTUFF"    /> More Other Stuff  
      </TD>
     </TR>

    </TABLE>
    <div id="NUMMsg"></div>

  </form>
```

The only field I really care about is the Num input field. I want to post a value to that field, run the search, and get the results in my coldfusion code. This is what I have so far:

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.someurl.com/"
        method="POST">
    <cfhttpparam name="Num" type="FormField" value="123456789123456" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#cfhttp.filecontent#" />
```

But when I go to the page the dump just says "`Connection Failure`". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give this a read: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2008/10/9/cfhttp-troubleshooting

Comment: Technical problems aside, I would be wary of scraping sites.  Changes in structure can break your scraper.  The site's terms of use may prohibit this, especially if you are doing it for more than personal use.  Finally, you may cause an unexpectedly high load if you hammer the site with no throttle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this website suggested a solution: http://australiansearchengine.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/cfhttp-connection-failure/

They suggested adding the following cfhttpparam tags:

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="te" value="deflate;q=0">
```

Now I no longer get a connection failure :)

Comment: I run into this quite a bit. It's an IIS thing, and our ColdFusion servers at work are IIS, so it made for a lot of hair-pulling when we first ran into that issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your sample code what the submit action URL is? It's blank. Maybe the site sets it using JavaScript etc.?

You also probably need to post the `displayType` form variable as that is a check box and some value probably needs to be provided.

Beware screen scraping - it can be a maintenance nightmare. if there is anyway to use an official API they provide you should do it because as soon as they change their code (post URL / markup etc.) your code could very well break.